# Conditional hibernate validations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

```
public class MyDomain {
    String test;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]")
    public String getTest() {
        return this.test;
    }
}
```

I've written a `commons` library with default validation: the test string should never be blank.

But in one application I want to explicit allow blanks here for this parameter.

Question: how can I make the `@Pattern` validation conditional, eg based on a `application.properties` value?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom validator for `@NotBlank` which takes the setting from *application.properties* into account.

When configuring this validator, e.g. through an XML constraint mapping file, you'd have to disable the default validator for the constraint, letting only your new implementation take over.